# In TypeScript, how can a declaration omit multiple methods from a base type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

While searching for ways to fix errors in a `d.ts` file, I need to omit a few methods from the base type because the custom class I'm working on redefines them.

I found the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type) helper type, which is used in examples like this one :

```
type Foo = {
  a() : void;
  b() : void;
  c() : void;
  toString() : string;
};
type BaseFoo = Omit<Foo, "a">;
```

However, what if I need to remove both `a`, `b`, and `c` in `BaseFoo`?

It seems that I can do

```
type BaseFoo = Omit<Omit<Omit<Foo, "a">, "b">, "c">;
```

But is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use union:

```js
type BaseFoo = Omit<Foo, 'a'|'b'|'c'>;
```

Or just use `Pick<Foo,'toString'>`

Comment: You could also do `Omit<Foo, keyof MyCustomClass>` in order to omit specifically the properties which will be provided by the other class later.

Comment: @kaya3 good point